# Camera frame size too large?

Tags: camera

I can't figure out how to adjust the camera view frame. I've ringed it in orange so you know the frame I'm referring to. It's either too big, or far too small. How do I adjust the size of this?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Simply zoom in/out using the mousewheel.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work - I'm not referring to zooming in one the race car, I'm referring to changing the size of the camera view that's ringed in orange on my image. I'm not sure of the technical term, but I know that if you press 'home' it'll take up the whole viewport (which I also don't want).

Comment: Oh right sorry :). Uncheck that blue checkmark "Camera to view" then zoom in/out

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Properties` Editor → `Output` tab → `Format` panel.  If you want a more landscape / portrait view, you can change the `Resolution`.  You can get basically any ratio.

[image]